# Stopping video playing in webview, navigation controller

Tags: uiwebview, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, youtube, ipad

I have built a navigation controller that on the final page displays a video relating to previous choices. This part works fine. The video is embed from youtube onto a webpage and displayed via a webview.

```
<iframe type="text/html" id="video" width="100%" height="50%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID" frameborder="0"><br/></iframe>
```

The problem I'm having is when I click back through the navigation controller the video (well sound) continues to play in the background. This only happens on the iPad as the video is played in the window, where as on the iPhone it is played in a new modal window.

How can I stop this? any help welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 7):

You need to load a blank page into the UIWebView to stop the audio:

[yourWebView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];

Comment: I had the same problem in a collectionView where each cell embedded a webView.
I tried to add this line on the prepareForReuse method but it didn't work, but it worked on the method

    `-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`